# subseting data that starts with a letter

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataset with 45 columns and >8000 observations. One of the variables in the columns is city-name. I want to remove all observations that are located in cities that begin with the letter "S". How would I do this? I'm pretty new to R, so sorry if this is simple, but I couldn't find any information through search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return only those rows beginning with a capital "S" using the `substr()`-ing function:

```
dat[ substr( dat$City, 1 ,1) == "S" , ]
```

Could also have used:

```
dat[ grepl("^S", dat$City) , ]
```

The second option is a very simple regular expression. Look at ?regex and ?grep.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr`'s `filter` function, although I have no idea how fast it is compared to other methods:

```
cities <- c("Some", "Random", "Cities", "Stack", "Overflow", "Bla", "Foo")
df <- data.frame(x = seq_along(cities), cities)
require(dplyr)
> df  %>% filter(!grepl("^[Ss]", cities))
  x   cities
1 2   Random
2 3   Cities
3 5 Overflow
4 6      Bla
5 7      Foo
```

Answer (score 0):

awk would be better for this. Something like

```
cat data | awk -F<delimiter> '{if (match($<1-indexed col num>, "^[^sS].*")) { print $0 }}'
```

You can do it in grep, but it get's sloppy (comma is the delimiter)

```
cat data | grep -E '^([^,]*,){<0-indexed col num>}[^sS]'
```